# GitHub - Private repository - add Collaborator by another Collaborator

Tags: github

is it possible that Collaborator in my Repository can add another Collaborator? In Settings -> Actions -> Actions permissions -> I checked option "Allow all actions", but still is not possible.

Thank you for your help.

[image: Collaborators access]

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you give them permissions in GitHub, IIRC.  Go to Settings -> Manage Access -> and if necessary "Add People" otherwise you can find the collaborator you've already added and give them admin privileges.  This will allow them to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I probably still missing something. Through "Add People" I can add new Collaborators in my repository, thats not a problem. But this Collaborators are not able to add new people. because they dont have option "Manage Access" at all. If I click on already added Collaborator it opens only his profile.[Collaborator setting][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qknf2.png

Comment: You have to go to Manage Access yourself.  This collaborator, whomever they are, next to their github username will be a dropdown menu.  You need to make sure it says "Admin"

Comment: I checked it and next to username I couldn't find any dropdown menu as you can see on this image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/qknf2.png . Or Maybe I still missing something?

Comment: Could it be a premium feature or perhaps you don't have admin permissions? Mine looks like this. https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=504498966265