# Add a user who can add collaborators to shared repository on GitHub

Tags: github, collaboration

I was wondering if it was possible at all, in GitHub, to add a user or a collaborator, to my repo who would also have the privilege to add other collaborators ?

I have added three collaborators to three of my repos, however, one of these collaborators is required to have the same privileges as me on the three repos and one of the requirements is that, that collaborator should be able to invite other collaborators, should he so wish, to these repos.

Any pointers ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to change your namespace from "yours" to an [organization](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/collaborating-with-groups-in-organizations/about-organizations) and from there you can create [teams](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-access-to-your-organizations-repositories).

Comment: Thanks Asghar. I read the documentation links you provided. Apparently, I can upgrade to Organisations just didn't realise that.

Upon attempting to convert, it gives me a message about how "destructive and irreversible" this process could be. So, I've decided against it for now until I've taken proper precautions. However, if I was to upgrade my personal account to an organisation, your suggestion would have solved my query.

So thanks once again buddy !

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what level of GitHub abilities you have.
Check the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70257208/github-private-repository-add-collaborator-by-another-collaborator) .

If you do not have the options detailed in the solution, consider moving the repo out of private.

Comment: Thanks for your response Arjun. I did come across the page whose link you posted before posting my question.

The issue with the page whose link you posted is that it's reply is not very clear about it's instructions because I could not find the pathways mentioned (Settings -> Manage Access -> and if necessary "Add People" otherwise .... ) for the suggested solution.

But thanks once again anyway ! :)